# C# regex to parse PHP function call list file

Tags: c#, regex

I have a simple problem. I have a PHP file which contains a lot of function-calls like this one:

```
return self::_Call('client_changePassword',Array(
    $token,
    $password,
    $user_token
));
```

The name and the number of parameters can vary but the call itself always have this structure, including spaces and linebreaks.

What I need is a regular expression that will grab all these calls from the PHP file and split them into the function name (client_changePassword) and a group of parameters. Since the file has several hundreds of different calls, it needs to be reasonably fast, too.

The regular expression would be used within C# as part of a console application that will generate a simple code analysis. Basically, I need a list of methods plus parameters that PHP calls in the source and compare it with a list of definitions that is stored in a different project. This would help our code reviews a lot.

No, this is **not** PHP-related even though I'm trying to parse PHP code. My system can't run any PHP code and I don't even want to run PHP code.

Comment: WTH? you marked the accepted answer that contains a PHP solution and you still insist on C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
return\s+self::_Call\('(?<name>[^']+)'\s*,\s*[Aa]rray\((?:\s+\$(?<param>[^,)\n]+),?\r?\n)+
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=return%5cs%2bself%3a%3a_Call%5c(%27(%3f%3cname%3e%5b%5e%27%5d%2b)%27%5cs*%2c%5cs*%5bAa%5drray%5c((%3f%3a%5cs%2b%5c%24(%3f%3cparam%3e%5b%5e%2c)%5cn%5d%2b)%2c%3f%5cr%3f%5cn)%2b&i=return+self%3a%3a_Call(%27client_changePassword%27%2cArray(%0d%0a++++%24token%2c%0d%0a++++%24password%2c%0d%0a++++%24user_token%0d%0a))%3b)

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Added a few modifications to create this one, which is slightly better: `return\s+self::_Call\('(?<name>[^']+)'\s*,\s*[Aa]rray\((?:\s+\$(?<param>[^,^)^\r^\n]+),?\r?\n)+`

Comment: Yes, named captures are way better and more readable. However, `[^,^)^\‌​r^\n]` is a bit clumsy, I'd use `[^,)\‌​r\n]` (or `[^,)\n]` since regexstorm complains of `\r\n` inside the character class).

Comment: `[^,)\‌​r\n]` works fine for me, so I've changed it into that. I still need to check for both \r and \n since there's no guarantee in which order they will appear in the PHP file.

Comment: It might be even unnecessary if the file was created in Linux/Unix since linebreaks are just `\n` there.

Comment: The PHP file is either generated on a Mac or Windows, depending on the developer...